# Why React.Memo() keeps rendering my component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I made an example to get to know more deeply the React.Memo().

I tried to pass a string from the `parent` to the `child`. then the component wasn't rendred except the first default rerending.

But When I passed an `array` from the `parent` to the `child` the components get re-render.

So why the component keeps re-render when passing `arrays` and `objects` and not re-render when passing `string`.

Is that related to the `reference values` and `primitive values` of `javascript`?

here's the code for what was I trying to do.

the `parent`:

```
import Child from "./Child";

export default function App() {
  const name = {
    firstName: "Amr"
  };

  return <Child name={name} />;
}
```

The `Child`

```
import React from "react";

const Child = ({ name }) => {
  const name1 = "Amr";

  const name2 = "Amr";

  // console.log(name1 === name2);

  const obj1 = {
    name: "Mohamed"
  };

  const obj2 = {
    name: "Mohamed"
  };

  const arr1 = ["Amr"];

  const arr2 = ["Amr"];

  console.log(arr1 === arr2);

  // console.log(obj1 === obj2); => obj1 => refrence number 1
  // obj2 => refrence number 2
  // 1 === 2;
  // false

  areEqual(name, {
    firstName: "Amr"
  });

  return <h2>{name.firstName}</h2>;
};

// javascript [] {} => refrence value
// javascript '' or anythinng primtive value;

// obj1 = 1, obj2 = 2;
// obj1 === obj2 result false 1 === 2

function areEqual(prevProps, nextPops) {
  if (prevProps === nextPops) {
    console.log("equal");
  } else {
    console.log("not equal");
  }
}

export default React.memo(Child, areEqual);
```

I used a function also `areEqual` that returns `true` or `false` based on if the `prevProps` and `nextProps` are equal or not.

This function already returns for me `true` when I pass a `String` and `false` when I pass an `array`.

So, am I right or there's something missing.

Thanks

UPDATE:

If what I mentioned is right, so the `React.memo()` will be useless.

Is that Right?

Comment: Can you create a sandbox where you can reproducible problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default `React.memo()` does a shallow comparison of props and objects of props - and this is why you were experiencing rerenders when props were of type 'object', because reference recreates on each rerender.

`React.memo` receives two argument(2nd one is optional), and second one is custom equality function which you can use in order to stabilize rerenders when having props as non primitive values. So, for example, you can do something like this: `React.memo(SomeComponent, (prevProps, currentProps) => isDeepEqual(prevProps.someObject, currentProps.someObject))`.

Meaning that `React.memo` is not useless, it just uses shallow comparison by default, but also offers you posibillity to provide it with custom equality checker which you might wanna use in your example. Either you shall use deep equality check within React.memo, or you shall stabilize props in parent component by wrapping their value with useMemo.

Comment: Can you provide isDeepEqual funtion refers to ? its from which library

Comment: You can use deep equality function from `lodash`

Answer (score 2):

It depends on their parent components some times it is necessary React.memo
But in your case, as you said, its reference changes every time you define an array or object. I recommend you to use React.useMemo. For example:

```js
const user = React.useMemo(() => {
    return {
    firstName: "Amr"
  }
}, []); // Second parameter works same as useCallback
```

React.memo wont re-render the component because `user` props didn't change